# Why doesn't this compiler barrier enforce ordering?

Tags: c, gcc, arduino, avr

I was looking at the documentation on the Atmel website and I came across this [example](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/optimization_1optim_code_reorder.html) where they explain some issues with reordering.

Here's the example code:

```
#define cli() __asm volatile( "cli" ::: "memory" )
#define sei() __asm volatile( "sei" ::: "memory" )

unsigned int ivar;

void test2( unsigned int val )
{
  val = 65535U / val;

  cli();

  ivar = val;

  sei();
}
```

In this example, they're implementing a critical region-like mechanism. The cli instruction disables interrupts and the sei instruction enables them. Normally, I would save the interrupt state and restore to that state, but I digress...

The problem which they note is that, with optimization enabled, the division on the first line actually gets moved to after the cli instruction. This can cause some issues when you're trying to be inside of the critical region for the shortest amount of time as possible.

How come this is possible if the cli() MACRO expands to inline asm which explicitly clobbers the memory? How is the compiler free to move things before or after this statement?

Also, I modified the code to include memory barriers before every statement in the form of `__asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` and it doesn't seem to change anything.

I also removed the memory clobber from the cli() and sei() MACROs, and the generated code was identical.

Of course, if I declare the test2 function argument as volatile, there is no reordering, which I assume to be because volatile statements can't be reordered with respect to other volatile statements (which the inline asm technically is). Is my assumption correct?

Can volatile accesses be reordered with respect to volatile inline asm?

Can non-volatile accesses be reordered with respect to volatile inline asm?

What's weird is that Atmel claims they need the memory clobber just to enforce the ordering of volatile accesses with respect to the asm. That doesn't make any sense to me.

If the compiler barrier isn't the proper solution for this, then how could I go about preventing any outside code from "leaking" into the critical region?

If anyone could shed some light, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: `val`'s address is never taken, so it could have been declared with the storage-class specifier `register`. Consequently, the `"memory"` clobber doesn't have to apply to it.

Comment: Indeed, when I tried compiling this on x86-64 with `-O2`, `val` actually did get put in a register (and the division was between the `cli/sei`).  And in fact, the same occurred even after I added `(void)&val;` inside the function.

Comment: @EOF That makes sense. The compiler probably kept it in a register as part of the optimization. So how would one go about preventing the division from being moved to after the cli instruction?

Comment: Take `unsigned int *ptr = &val;`, pass the pointer as an input operand into the `asm()`?

Comment: @EOF: I don't  think you even need the pointer.  In my test, simply adding `val` as an input operand to the `asm()` had the desired effect.  Which makes sense - we don't really care about whether `val` is in memory or a register, we just want its value to be computed before the `asm`.

Comment: @EOF Adding `val` as an input operand works in this case, but is there a way to handle the generic case? It seems like I would need to add every variable as an input operand, which would make it hard to provide something like a generic “critical region” API.

This also makes me wonder if the <avr/atomic.h> header is completely broken for many use cases. That header defines MACROs which allow you to declare atomic blocks of code and it uses these same instructions. It seems like it's possible for code that was supposed to be inside of the block to be moved outside of it without realizing it.

Comment: @Corvette1250 There is generally no point in protecting objects that could have been declared as `register`. They are, by definition, not shared. If the object has had its address taken (and the address could conceivably be visible outside of the function), the compiler should not reorder around the `"memory"` -clobber.

Comment: @eof, nate: it would be great if someone could condense this interesting discussion into an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm afraid I have to disagree with you here. While 'generally' there is no point, in this specific case there is. Time spent with interrupts disabled must be kept to an absolute minimum. And moving *any* memory access (even non-escaped ones) inside a cli/sei could potentially be disastrous (think: page fault with interrupts disabled). The only way to ensure no extra instructions "leak" inside this code would be to (like Atmel says) do something like `cli\nmov %1,%0\nsei`.  Although you can kinda/maybe do that with `__attribute__ ((noinline)) test2` and use inputs like you said.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I think it's EOF you're disagreeing with, not me.  But while it's certainly true that there are cases where unexpected memory access in a critical section would be bad, I don't know of any compiler that has a way to guarantee that.  I think most compiler vendors would agree with Atmel: we're not gonna make that promise, so if you care that much about the code, you better just write the whole critical section in assembler.

Answer (score 3):

> How come this is possible if the cli() MACRO expands to inline asm which explicitly clobbers the memory? How is the compiler free to move things before or after this statement?

This is due to implementation details of `avr-gcc`: The compiler's support library, libgcc, provides many functions written in assembly for performance; including functions for integer division like `__udivmodhi4`.  Not all of these functions clobber all of the [callee-used registers as specified by the avr-gcc ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Call-Used_Registers). In particular, `__udivmodhi4` does not clobber the `Z` register.

`avr-gcc` makes use of this as follows:  On machines without 16-bit division instruction like AVR, GCC would issue a library call instead of generating code for it inline.  `avr-gcc` however pretends that the architecture **does have** such division instruction and models it as having an effect on processor registers just like the library call.  Finally, after all code analyzes and optimizations, the avr backend prints this instruction as `[R]CALL __udivmodhi4`.  Let's call this a ***transparent call***, i.e. a call which the compiler analysis does not see.

**Example**

```c
int div (int a, int b, volatile const __flash char *z)
{
    int ab;

    (void) *z;
    asm volatile ("" : "+r" (a));
    ab = a / b;
    asm volatile ("" : "+r" (ab));
    (void) *z;

    return ab;
}
```

Compile this with `avr-gcc -S -Os -mmcu=atmega8 ...` to get assembly file `*.s`:

```
div:
    movw  r30,r20
    lpm   r18,Z
    rcall __divmodhi4
    movw  r24,r22
    lpm   r18,Z
    ret
```

**Explanation**

`(void) *z` reads one byte from flash, and in order to use `lpm` instruction, the address must be in the `Z` register accomplished by `movw  r30,r20`.  After reading via `lpm`, the compiler issues `rcall __divmodhi4` to perform signed 16-bit division.  If this was an ordinary (non-transparent) call, the compiler would know nothing about the internal working of the callee, but as the avr backend models the call by hand, the compiler knows that the instruction sequence **does not change `Z`** and hence may use `Z` again after the call without any further ado.  This allows for better code generation due to less register pressure, in particular `z` need not be saved / restored around the division.

The `asm` just serves to order the code: It is volatile and hence must not be reordered against the volatile read `*z`.  And the `asm` must not be reordered against the division because the `asm` changes `a` and `ab` – at least that's what we are pretending and telling the compiler by means of the constraints.  (These variables are not actually changed, but that does not matter here.)

> Also, I modified the code to include memory barriers before every statement in the form of `__asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` and it doesn't seem to change anything.

The division does not touch memory (it's a transparent call without memory clobber) hence the compiler machinery may reorder it against memory clobber / accesses.

If you need a specific order, then you'll have to introduce artificial dependencies like in in my example above.

In order to tell apart ordinary calls from transparent ones, you can dump the generated assembly in the `.s` file by means of `-save-temps -dp` where `-dp` prints insn names:

```
void func0 (void);

int func1 (int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

void func2 (void)
{
    func0();
}
```

Every call that's neither `call_insn` nor `call_value_insn` is a transparent call,  `*divmodhi4_call` in this case:

```
func1:
    rcall __divmodhi4    ;  17  [c=0 l=1]  *divmodhi4_call
    movw r24,r22         ;  18  [c=4 l=1]  *movhi/0
    ret                  ;  23  [c=0 l=1]  return

func2:
    rjmp func0           ;  5   [c=0 l=1]  call_insn/3
```