# Atmel driver and GCC memory barrier use case

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, avr, avr-gcc

While I was taking a look at some driver implementations from the Atmel Software Framework, I came across several cases where they used a memory barrier.

Barrier definition:

```
#define barrier()        asm volatile("" ::: "memory")
```

**Example 1** (interrupt helper functions):

```
static inline void cpu_irq_restore(irqflags_t flags)
{
    barrier();
    SREG = flags;
}
```

This barrier makes sense to me. Since `cpu_irq_restore` gets implicitly inlined, it prevents the critical (from an execution order perspective) SREG assignment to be re-ordered from the actual function call location.

As a side note: `SREG` is defined as a special function register defined as:

```
#define _SFR_MEM8(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
```

**Example 2** (from AVR TWI driver):

```
static inline status_code_t twim_release(void)
{
    /* First wait for the driver event handler to indicate something
     * other than a transfer in-progress, then test the bus interface
     * for an Idle bus state.
     */
    while (OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS == transfer.status);

    while (! twim_idle(transfer.bus)) { barrier(); }

    status_code_t const status = transfer.status;

    transfer.locked = false;

    return status;
}
```

This second use case however, is not clear to me. In what way could the compiler optimize that code, so that it breaks without the `barrier()`?

I think I understand the basic reasoning behind software memory barriers after reading [this article](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/optimization_1optim_code_reorder.html).

What is the reasoning behind using the barrier in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

The `twim_idle` function probably does something like read the value of a TWI-related special function register and check some bits in it.  Without the barrier, the danger is that the compiler might optimize the reading of that register and move it to before the second loop.  So then that second loop would behave like this:

```
bool idle = twim_idle(transfer.bus);
while (!idle);
```

This is an optimization that would make the loop faster and it would be valid for reads of normal variables, but it would obviously cause a problem in this case.  Putting a barrier in the loop should prevent that optimization from happening.

In reality, you should not need that memory barrier because all the special function registers are qualified with the `volatile` keyword, so the compiler will not attempt to cache accesses to them.

Comment: Atmel states in the liked article: "Note that even a volatile asm instruction can be moved relative to other code, including across jump instructions. [...] Similarly, you can't expect a sequence of volatile asm instructions to remain perfectly consecutive." It is not entirely clear to me under what circumstances.

Comment: I agree, that in the first example, a second barrier after the SREG assignment would make sense.

Comment: I am not sure about the `twim_idle()`. It does indeed access registers, but the compiler isn't allowed to just reorganize the logical sequence of those two while loops, or is it? If that is the case, one would have to consider this kind of problem all the time. However, since they used barrier(), either it is something specific about this code, or its just out of place and not required.

Comment: FYI: That quote from the 'Atmel' docs was actually lifted from gcc's [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Also, is this related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37897848/2189500) recent question?

Comment: As for not needing the "memory" clobber for SREG in `cpu_irq_restore`, I'm not so sure.  I don't know what that register controls (I don't speak Atmel; at all), but if it could be used for multi-threading, I could see a second thread trying to read data that the change to SREG signals is available.  But if the first thread still has values in registers that haven't been flushed to memory, you could introduce a race condition.  Unless you have a memory clobber.

Comment: I came across that question during my search before asking this. I wasn't aware of the gcc docs link, thanks.

Comment: Regarding `cpu_irq_restore` my though was (as mentioned in the original question) that its required since the function is "inline" and the `SREG = flags;` assignment could end up a few lines up or below the intended location where the function is called. Saving/restoring the status register is something where this is normally not desired or even critical. This is why I agree that it should probably be surrounded with a barrier?

Comment: The link was where atmel probably acquired that text, but the newer gcc docs do a better job of describing inline asm (if I say so myself). Probably not any info you don't already have, tho. 'Intended location' is a term that means a lot to programmers, and almost nothing to compilers. Clobbers won't keep gcc from moving code before/after SREG, just code that it thinks would be 'affected' (see corvette's question). Clobbers can't keep gcc from calcing `val` in a 'bad' place (ie inside the cli), but input parameters (as Nate says) can help. Not sure what problem is solved by a trailing clobber?

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove some claims.  (The memory barrier in Example 1 seems OK to me because it ensures that any reads or writes from non-volatile variables will not be moved across the barrier.  If the user is accessing variables from both an ISR and the main loop and they are not properly sychrnonizing things, this memory barrier could prevent *some* bugs (but not all).)

Comment: @Rev1.0: I'm not sure why you are talking about volatile asm instructions in this thread.  What asm instructions are you talking about?  I think the code above is probably implemented without assembly.

Comment: @Rev1.0: My answer does not consider the first loop, I was just looking at the second loop.  Why are you asking about reorganizing the logical sequence of both loops?  I was never claiming that the loops would get intertwined; I was only considering the second loop and whether it would behave correctly.